# Open DatePicker with suggested date

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I need to open a DatePicker with a default date based on the YEAR-MONTH-DAY_OF_MONTH properties of a GregorianCalendar.

Here is the code where I open the DatePicker:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

For exemple, if my values are like this:

- MyCalendar.YEAR = 2017
- MyCalendar.MONTH = 2
- MyCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH = 22

The default value set when I open the DatePicker would be:

[image]

What do I have to add to do that?

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically straight from [Android | Pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker)

Plus, just like any other Fragment, you can use `set` and `get`-`Arguments` to pass data into the fragment.

Details: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(int year,int month,int day) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("year", year);
        // put others...

        Fragment f = new DatePickerFragment();
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Update using the arguments
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            year = args.getInt("year");
            // get others...
        }

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

And use that `newInstance` method.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(2017,02,07);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```